# When a DropDownList change its html when change

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

when a html DropDownList is selected, will the browser change its 's html automotially?

For example from

`<option value="val">some text</option>`

to

`<option value="val" selected>some text</option>`

should it automatically change itself or do i have to do change it manually in java script

same questions apply to checkbox.

any idea will be appreciated

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.  If the user is changing the selected value then that action updates the selected value.  If a user isn't doing it and you want to do it with code then, yes, you'd have to do it with code.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks David, i have updated the question. I want to know when user changes the selected value if the dropdownlist's html will change accordingly. I noticed it actually does not, no selected attribute is added to option element

Comment: It's possible that the debugging tools don't show an updated DOM, sure.  But why is that even important?  Are you suggesting that HTML `select` elements don't actually work?  Because I'm fairly certain they do.  Is there something you're trying to do that isn't working, or are you just pointing out that a particular browser debugging tool (which you haven't mentioned) doesn't have a particular feature?

Comment: Thanks David, i just checked with jquery, the DOM is updated, just the debugging tool did not update. By the way im using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

> > when a html DropDownList is selected, will the browser to change its options html automotially?

Yes. You can check it with any developer tool in your browser. 
For example:
in Chrome, right click, choose "Inspect Element". See

```
<option value="val">some text</option>
```

Then, select an option, the html will change to

```
<option value="val" selected>some text</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does change the DOM, but the Chrome debug tool simply does not reflect this change, which is why i was confused in the first place, thanks anyway